Website image rendering issue on Google SERP
I have a website in React, and it's a E-commerce website. On SERP when a catagory page renders, it shows images of popular products.
What can I do ?
Nothing is wrong with the website; all images are compressed and small size.
Most of the time SERP images are not relevant to the product page.

Its a known issue.
You should try to tie your needed images to product urls.
Use structured data intensively, specially product images,  https://schema.org/primaryImageOfPage, Open Graph, shopping feed.
Look that no other images are associated with product, specially in social media.
Create image sitemap and guarantee, that no other images are indexed - like: product images are hosted by your own, all other images - on deindexed / disallowed CDN.
In React environment are all onpage hints unreliable. Make use of pre-rendering.

Please check how your alt tags for images are being generated, as they may affect the enhanced search engine results.
Ideally, each image tag should correspond to its respective product rather than a general category.
Additionally, you might want to consider creating an image sitemap to explicitly associate images with specific pages. You can read more about it here.
